# PivotTable with multiple conditions to count unique items

Tags: excel, pivot-table

Following is the portion of my table in Excel:

```
A   B   C   D       E
5   10  1   18316   3
5   11  1   18313   3
5   11  2   18002   3
5   11  3   10825   3
5   12  1   18316   3
5   12  2   18001   3
5   12  3   10825   3
5   13  1   18313   3
5   13  2   18002   3
5   14  1   18316   3
5   14  2   18001   3
5   14  3   18002   3
5   15  1   18313   3
5   16  1   18316   3
5   16  2   18002   3
5   16  3   18313   3
5   17  1   18313   3
5   17  2   18002   3
5   17  3   18316   3
5   20  1   18313   3
5   21  1   18316   3
5   21  2   18001   3
5   21  3   18313   3
15  10  1   47009   3
15  10  2   40802   3
15  11  1   47009   3
15  12  1   47010   3
15  12  2   47009   3
15  13  1   47009   3
15  13  2   47010   3
15  14  1   47010   3
```

What I want to achieve is the following:

To be able to calculate the count of a number in column D for every unique B and A with respect to C (if D is at the Max of C or not)

Output something like:

```
Filter: 18001 on Column D
    5
     12 1 Non-Max
     14 1 Non-Max
     21 1 Non-Max
```

Similarly if the filter is changed to 18316:

```
5
    10 1 Max
    12 1 Non-Max
    14 1 Non-Max
    16 1 Non-Max
    17 1 Max
    21 1 Non-Max
```

I have 20K rows of data that needs processing.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to be able to achieve close to the results you indicate from the data you have provided - but have no idea what you mean by "for every unique B and A with respect to C (if D is at the Max of C or not)". I applied a PivotTable as below:

[image: SO29424701 example]

`Max` and `Non-Max` being indicated by the relationship between `Count of E` and `Max of C` - which could be used in a simple formula to display `Max` or `Non-Max` outside the PivotTable.